# Create image on the fly and replace src of pre existing img tag

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I´m turning a little crazy with this and I hope you can help me.

Use case:
A user provides his name. When he clicks in a button, a request is sent to a back-end service which generates an image. Without refreshing the page, user should be able to see the new created image.

So I started with an img tag with a provisional image.

```
<img src="waiting.png" />
```

Then,  when the user click the button I execute the following function:

```
function loadingImage() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = userNameForImage;

    // This will print something like images/JJ.png
    console.log(userNameForImage);

    image.onload = function() {
      // Here resolve
    };
    image.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error('Could not load image at ' + userNameForImage));
    };
  });
}
```

userNameForImage is path + userName + extension.

When I try to resolve

```
resolve(image);
```

I receive this error: Error: Could not load image at images/JJ.png

Same thing if I use a setTimeout()

```
setTimeout(() => resolve(image), 10000);
```

Remember that the image is created by a back-end service. So it is async an it takes some time. Usually, no more than 6 seconds. In any case, I cannot resolve the operation after the image is created and the loaded.

In pseudocode would be

1. User provides his name
2. User clicks in a button
3. A function attaches a listener to the img and a promise is created.
4. A request is made to backend service which will create an image.
5. Once the image can be loaded (== exists) the promise should be resolved
6. Then, the src should be updated or replaced.

Can anyone provide some guidance?
Im totally new with promises and Im really stuck. Thanks

Comment: And which part causes the service to create the image? Clearly it doesnt exist when `image.src` gets set and the request is started.

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for your comment. When user clicks, a request to the endpoint /create is made and a response is pending until the image is created and THEN the response is sent `await res.send({ status: 'loaded!' });` I truly appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: cool. Where is the clientside code?

Comment: Thanks again =D So, I have the server code inside server.js and the client code inside public/index.html

Comment: ... we need to see it to be able to help ...